# Javascript calculation not returning to text box

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple table where a user puts in their length, width, height and number of pieces and then calculate the cubic feet, with the answer displayed in the table. So I've tried to do that here but I do not know why no answer is being displayed. The ID's are all correct. I've tried using ParseFloat and putting parentheses around each variable in the calculation and that doesn't seem to do anything. What could the problem be?

Thanks for having a look.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Cubic Feet</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">


function Calculate()
{
var qty1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
var len1 = document.getElementById('l1').value;
var width1 = document.getElementById('w1').value;
var height1 = doument.getElementById('h1').value;
var cube1 = qty1*(len1*width1*height1);

form.cuft1.value = cube1.tofixed(2);

}

function ClearForm(form)
{
form.q1.value = "";
form.l1.value = "";
form.w1.value = "";
form.h1.value = "";
form.cuft1.value = "";
}

// end of JavaScript functions -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">


<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton" onClick="Calculate(this.form.q1.value, this.form.h1.value, this.form.w1.value, this.form.l1.value, this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)">

<p>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Container 1 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q1" value=""></td>
<td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l1" value=""></td>
<td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w1" value=""></td>
<td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h1" value=""></td>
<td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft1" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The language attribute is obsolete. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead please.

Comment: @crush In fact it's better to use neither language nor type. The type always defaulted to "text/javascript". It has been made official in HTML5 but it worked in all browsers before.

Comment: @dystroy According to what? I believe that is the case only in HTML5.

Comment: @dystroy [The W3C Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html) does not say to omit `type`. It does, however, say that `language` is obsolete.

Comment: @crush [*The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type)

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` was default mime type even in IE4.

Comment: Alright, good to know.

Comment: @crush & dystroy - did not know that. Lots of obsolete tutorials out there. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a series of silly errors:

1. `documentgetElementById('w1').value;` should be `document.getElementById('w1').value;`
2. `doument.getElementById('h1').value;` should be `document.getElementById('h1').value;`
3. `form` is not defined. Try `var form = document.forms[0]`.
4. `cube1.tofixed(2);` should be `cube1.toFixed(2);`

All those errors could be easily caught by opening your browser's developer console...

Fixed, working version here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzcdx

Comment: +1 because nobody yet cared to upvote the most complete (and tested) answer.

Comment: Thanks. And kudos for your effort in evangelizing against DOM Level 0 methods.

Comment: This is what happens when I don't stop to have coffee and use NotePad to try and write javascript. I have bookmarked CodePen because that is pretty neat with the windows for the HTML, JS and CSS! +1 also. Thank you bfavaretto & dystroy

Answer (score 1):

```
this.form.q1.value
```

looks for an input with **name** `q1`.

Use this instead :

```
document.getElementById('q1').value
```

You have the same error in other points. It's better to always use the id.

Comment: @Shawn Everywhere. Don't use the form to find your inputs, simply use their id.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("cuft1").value = cube1.tofixed(2);
```